# Convert reddit's 'created' unix timestamp to readable date

Tags: javascript, date

I found reddit `created` and `created_utc` kinda weird to me. Can someone explain to me what am i missing here? When i'm subtracting comment creation date with `new Date()` i'm getting time from 2 weeks ago instead of date from 3 hours ago (for utc+2 timezone at 2 pm).

[CodePen for "playground"](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OgvRQN)

```js
fetch(`https://www.reddit.com/r/hearthstone/comments/6kkoyi.json`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res=>{
  const comments = res[1].data.children.map(obj => obj.data);
  let date = comments[0].created
  console.log("Should show: Saturday, 1 July 2017 11:13:39 or ~3 hours",
              "\nUnix: "+ date, 
              "\nDistance from now: "+ dateFns.distanceInWordsToNow(date),
              "\nFormatted: " + dateFns.format(date),
              "\nDate from now: "+ dateFns.format(new Date() - date))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.28.5/date_fns.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fetch/2.0.3/fetch.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timestamp is in seconds

So:

```
new Date(1498878149*1000);
```

Gives me:

```
2017-07-01T03:02:29.000Z
```

Comment: Ahh indeed, forgot about that multiplication by 1000.